# How could I store an "id" (urlparameter.optional) through a textboxfor()

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to store an id from url in a `textboxfor()`, but I don't obtain the result.  When i put "id" in a textbox, I obtain the correct result.  Instead, in a `textboxfor(model=> model.IDCantiere,new{@value="id"})`.  It doesn't run; please help me, I've attached the code fragments:

Controller.cs

```
// GET: CantiereOres/Create
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
    ViewBag.id =  id;
    //ViewBag.IdCantiere = new SelectList(db.Cantieres, "IdCantiere", "IdCantiere");
    ViewBag.IdPersona = new SelectList(db.CantierePersones, "IdPersona", "Persona");
    return View();
}

// POST: CantiereOres/Create
// Per proteggere da attacchi di overposting, abilitare le proprietà a cui eseguire il binding. 
// Per ulteriori dettagli, vedere https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "IdOre,IdCantiere,IdPersona,Ore,datetime")] CantiereOre cantiereOre)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.CantiereOres.Add(cantiereOre);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("details", "Cantieres", new { id = cantiereOre.IdCantiere });
    }

    ViewBag.IdCantiere = new SelectList(db.Cantieres, "IdCantiere", "IdCantiere", cantiereOre.IdCantiere);
    ViewBag.IdPersona = new SelectList(db.CantierePersones, "IdPersona", "Persona", cantiereOre.IdPersona);
    return View(cantiereOre);
}
```

View.cshtml:

```
@model archeagroup.Models.CantiereOre

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.TextBox("id")

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>CantiereOre</h4>

        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdCantiere, "IdCantiere", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.IdCantiere,  new {@value ="id", @class = "form-control" } )
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IdCantiere,  new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdCantiere, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdPersona, "IdPersona", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("IdPersona", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdPersona, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ore, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ore, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ore, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Details", "Cantieres")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want 2441 to be in this textbox right?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.IdCantiere,  new {@value ="id", @class = "form-control" } )
```

Then in your controller, instead of this:

```
ViewBag.id =  id;
```

Do this:

```
Model.IdCantiere = id;
```

And change your textbox to:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.IdCantiere,  new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Which will put (from your screenshot) 2441 in the textbox you indicated.

**EDIT**: So you need to return an instance of archeagroup.Models.CantiereOre from your controller Create method:

```
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
   var model = new acheagroup.Models.CantiereOre();
   model.IdCantiere = id;
   model... //other assignments - use this instead of ViewBag

   return View(model);
}
```

With this the above code will work since it will be fed from the model.

Comment: Sorry Brian I'm new in MVC if I modify controller code as you suggets I obtain error CS0103 Name 'Model' doesn't exist in current context, Where are my mistakes

Comment: I try to create a 'public int IdCantiere { get;  set; }' but nothing happens

Comment: You need to return a model class from the view, as in my edit above.

Comment: Thank you very much everything runs great!!! I need to understand many things about C# yet.